# What does following is mean in ruby?

Tags: ruby

Can any one tell me? what does following means in ruby program:

```
obj = myClass.new
(Err("Error: Can't get myClass instance"); exit) if obj == nil
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What exactly is unclear to you?

Comment: the second statement in the above code. What it does?

Comment: side note: that code should be refactored (probably using `unless`), concatenating commands with `;` is generally considered bad style. You can also refactor `Err` into some method that also exits the script and now you can write simply: `obj = myClass.new or error("can't get myClass instance")`.

Comment: a question: how is it possible that `myClass.new` returns `nil`? that sounds unlikely to me.

Comment: @tokland `def myClass.new; nil; end`; yes, it's unlikely that someone would use that, but it's possible. :)

Comment: @SonySantos: yeah, that would be one way to force it :-) Anyway, I am not sure where this snippet may come from, it looks very, very weird. OP?

Comment: @tokland I agree; the weirdest thing I saw in the code is `Err(...)` instead of `Err.new(...)` or `err(...)`; but [you can define methods with capitalized names](http://rubychallenger.blogspot.com.br/2012/03/capitalized-function-names.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# create instance of a class with non-standard name. 
obj = myClass.new
# call function Err and exit if myClass.new returned nil
(Err("Error: Can't get myClass instance"); exit) if obj == nil
```

I find this code confusing. Under normal circumstances, `new` never returns nil. If it does in your app, then you have much more complicated code somewhere. This one is not your biggest problem :)

Comment: so does it mean that "if" condition is executed before the execution of Err() function?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev imagine you have overloaded 'new' and have a singleton class. Also imagine new will return nil unless a initialize method has been called(or other preconditions were met). Not saying this is the best way to do that but at least it makes some sense.

Comment: @izomorphius: yes, that's what I'm saying. This innocent suffix condition is nothing compared to *that*. :)

Answer (score 3):

This is equivalent to:

```
obj = myClass.new
if obj == nil
   Err("Error: Can't get myClass instance")
   exit
end
```

I would personally use the version I show above as I consider it more readable.

Comment: +1. I'd use `unless obj` instead of `if`, but there's a lot of ways to do the same (like `if obj.nil?` etc.). :)

Answer (score 0):

It means that `Err("Error: Can't get myClass instance")` is called followed by `exit` if `obj` is `nil`.

In ruby you can write an if statement like this: `(code) if (expression)`.